# Trouble with Typekit fonts in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to import TypeKit fonts into my Tailwind config. I have included the .css file like so in my index: `https://use.typekit.net/kcz3fka.css`. Inside my tailwind.config.cjs file I have the definition:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['index.html', 'src/**/*.tsx'],
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      container: {
        center: true,
      },
      fontFamily: {
        display: ['"katarine-web"', ...theme.fontFamily.sans],
        body: ['"katarine-web"', ...theme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
};
```

I've tried escaping the katarine name as well as with and without double quotes. Neither seem to work as expected. What should I be doing to ensure Katarine can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['index.html', 'src/**/*.tsx'], // include your purge target files
  mode: 'jit',
  theme: {
    extend: { 
      container: {
        'center': true,
      },
      fontFamily: { // if you want extend 'katrarine-web', then just add them instead other originals.
        'display': ['katarine-web'],
        'body': ['katarine-web'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
};
```

also, check this [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/presets#extending-multiple-presets).

Happy coding :)

Comment: Oh man you're right I was spreading the default over it *slaps forehead*.